# Rails says No route matches but I see it in `rake routes`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails says:
No route matches {:action=>"import", :controller=>"admin/users"}

but `rake routes` shows:

```
import_admin_user POST   /admin/users/:id/import(.:format)        admin/users#import
```

My routes.rb looks like:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users do
      member do
        post :import
      end
    end    
  end
```

What am I missing? Rails 5.0.7

Comment: Could you show me where you called that route?

Comment: Like this: `form_tag({:action => 'import'})`

Comment: You define `:member` in the routes, why didn't you use `:form_for` instead of `:form_tag`. Are you using `RailsUJS`? You can make it simpler with `:data_method`. eg: `link_to text, path, method: :post`.

Comment: @fongfan999 ok show me what that looks like in routes.rb and in my view please.

Comment: Please tell me your feature, I think I can define routes properly for you.

Comment: I just want to add an action called "import" to my controller.

Comment: You want import all users or just one user? What do users need to do to import on UI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170011/discussion-between-fongfan999-and-pguardiario).

Comment: @pguardiario You could just say: `form_tag({url: import_admin_user_path})`

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users do
      collection do
        post :import
      end
    end
  end
```

Apparently collection is for actions that don't take an id.